# What is the best way to Upload to an Image Heavy website?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image-uploading

I have a client who wants me to develop a Stock Photography website. As you know, for stock photography, users upload huge files such as 10MB, 20MB or even 50MB or above. In addition to that, at the time of upload, we will have to create several different size thumbnails and store. This in itself will delay the upload process and would put extra stress on servers.

Can anyone please help me find the best method of upload in order to speed things up for the user and save server stress.  How does a site like Facebook for instance manage upload?  After much research I have come up with the following solutions, but they may not be enough. Can Node js or React js help in upload process?

My findings:
 1. Upload a single image and then create thumbnails on server and save them.  (This will Save some Bandwidth but increase server work)

2. Get the image on user machine create thumbnails (using javascript) and upload on server  (This will take more bandwidth because we are uploading same image on server with different size but save the server work)
3. Upload a single image with original size and when we need a different size then generate the needed thumbnail on the fly using server side script

Also, it seems like for faster response time, we can use a storage service like AMAZON S3 (this will be very helpful in long term, however the client does not want to use Amazon as it will be more and more costly to store more and more images in the future)

I thank you in advance

Comment: In other photo web sites, the image upload is handled by one type of server and then that image is placed in a queue on disk where it can be proceessed by other servers (creation of several sizes, copy to backup store, etc...).  The other servers do not participate in the web process and even if they are extremely busy, they do not affect the web server.  This does mean that uploaded images may take a short amount of time to get processed and appear on the site (if there is a busy queue).  If you use elastic resources, you can dial up or down the CPU you devote to processing images.

Comment: Your client should compare their own robust, reliable storage costs with Amazon storage costs.  I know at least one relatively large photo web site with zillions of terabytes of storage that uses Amazon because it's cheaper than their own storage costs.  They also use Amazon servers for processing the images as it can more easily scale upon demand.

Answer (score 0):

Your client sounds like a startup that might not have a big existing user base? Non-experienced founders often put huge weight on "scalability" features such as "how much will costs grow if users upload a terabyte of new images each month?".

These are almost always premature optimisations and your development time will likely cost more than image hosting in the first 6 - 12 months while you try to prove that you have product-market fit.

I would suggest you go with something like cloudinary.com. Users can upload directly to their servers so you don't have to handle any of the load and they'll create thumbnails for you on the fly for any required dimensions.

Once you have enough traction and your cloudinary expenses warrant it, you can hire an experienced development/devops team to build your own infrastructure for hosting, backups, and resizing images.

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup  on-fly image processing server using nginx , Operesty and lua. Here is the link - [Image Server](http://leafo.net/posts/creating_an_image_server.html)

If you are interested in writing own code for creating thumbnail , I will suggest you , for this process you should use FFmpeg and Java. I have used FFmpeg both with Node.js and Java.

FFmpeg is cpu insentive process and if your server have heavy image upload traffic then you need specific hardware / high end machine for this process.

It is perfectly fine to have writing your own program for this purpose or can setup openresty server, if you have low traffic and you can scale it later when traffic start growing.

And other option is to use [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com) which provide image processing  on-fly as well as provide CDN services also.

Here is few links in case you want to write your own code for above

[Crop-and-scale-image-using-ffmpeg](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Crop-and-scale-image-using-ffmpeg)

[Transcoding-in-NODEJS-using-FFMPEG](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Transcoding-in-NODEJS-using-FFMPEG)

[FFmpeg](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blog/tagged/ffmpeg)